# Adjusting button width and height according to device

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to create a keypad for an app that I'm playing with.  The keypad will be a standard four rows with the numbers 0 - 1, a decimal, and +/-.  Nothing special. I am attempting to get it to only take up 1/2 of vertical screen space.  Using constraints, I pinned the bottom left button to the left and bottom of the screen, and the bottom right button to the bottom and right of the screen.  I set the width and height of the left button, and then used Aspect Ratio on that button.  On the remaining bottom buttons, I control-drag left to the one next to it, and select Horizontal Spacing, Center Y, Equal Width, and Equal Height  I then control drag from each of the buttons above, to the button below, and select Vertical Spacing, Center X, Equal Width, and Equal Height from the list of constraints.  My thinking was that the bottom left button would adjust based on the device selected, and then all of the other buttons would adjust based on this button.

Apparently, I was wrong.  The buttons are nicely set up in that they remain above and next to one another, without any spaces, but they are not taking up exactly one half of the screen.  Depending on the device selected, there is proportionatally more or less space above them.  Apparently, I am either missing something, or I am totally approaching this the wrong way.

Any advice on how to accomplish this task would be appreciated.  I'm still learning about how constraints play with one another, but I thought that my idea was sound.  Make one button adjust itself to the correct size (Aspect Ratio on the bottom left button), and then force all of the other buttons to maintain the same width, height, and distance.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom left button is not going to adjust its size, because you gave it a fixed width and height. The buttons should not have any explicit widths or heights set on them. They should all be set to the same size, and as long as you have constraints going from the left edge to the right, that should set theirs widths. Their heights will also be set by virtue of the aspect ratio constraints.

This will cause the buttons to just their size based on the screen size, but it doesn't make them be half the height of the screen (that could only work for one screen size with a particular aspect ratio). To make the buttons take up half the vertical height of the screen, you would probably want to enclose them in a view that was that height. However, then you'll have a conflict between the aspect ratio of the buttons, and the aspect ratio of the screen. You either need to give up on the aspect ratio, or, not pin the right side of the buttons to the right side of the screen, and use an aspect ratio that will make the buttons all fit on the screen.

Comment: The reason that I input the width and height is because if I don't, I get warnings about frames being different at runtime.  I really am just guessing at the stuff based on what I know about how these things work.  Perhaps the what I don't know is affecting me more.  I'm just not sure how to make this work.  Aspect ratio seemed to be the way to go, but it doesn't act the way that I expected it to act.

The width of the buttons adjusts just fine with the scenario given above.  The height does not adjust at all.  That's where the problem with the buttons being too tall comes in.

Comment: @Scott I don't see how this: "width of the buttons adjusts just fine with the scenario given above" can be true if you set an explicit width for the buttons, unless you're getting warnings, and the system is breaking one or more constraints. If all the buttons across a row have equal width, and one of them has a set width, and you have spacing constraints running from the left edge to the right edge, then that adds up to a fixed number -- it shouldn't be able to adjust.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I really do.  But the buttons do scale down on the width.  I have the view set up so that it is three buttons across, taking up the entire screen.  And no matter which of the simulated devices I run on, the buttons all fit exactly.  Width wise, not height.
I only explicitly set the width and height for the first button.  The other buttons are set to same width, same height.  No warnings until I remove the explicit width and height.

Comment: @Scott I don't think that you have the constraints you think you do. Setting the width of the first button, and setting them all equal is the same as setting the width for all of them. Those 3 widths plus any spaces **have** to add up to a fixed number. It can't work for more than one screen width. If you can post your project somewhere, I'll look at it, but otherwise, I don't know what you're really doing.

Comment: Thanks.  I have uploaded the project here:
https://app.box.com/files/0/f/3666170919/Keypad_Project

Comment: @Scott I can't seem to get the file from that link. I tried setting up an account, but I still couldn't get it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  Apparently I don't know how to set that up correctly, either.  This link should work: https://app.box.com/s/ucpx1rwsu54kmn40dabt8qtwttyn6jff
I logged out and tried it and I was able to download the files.

Comment: @Scott As I suspected, When I run your app, I'm getting an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error in the console, and the system is removing the 200 width constraint that you put on the bottom left button. Are you not seeing these warnings in the console? I get no warnings if I remove both the width and height constraint on that lower left button.

Comment: Interesting.   I looked at Issues Navigator, and I didn't see any issues.  I went in to the project and removed the height and width constraints, and it didn't cause any issues in the Issues Navigator, but my buttons are taking up variable amounts of space in the view.

Comment: @Scott You need to decide what you want. The constraints you have now don't work. If you want the array of buttons to take half the height and the full width, then you need to get rid of the aspect ratio constraint. I would embed those buttons in another view (which will cause you to lose all the constraints you have now) that you set to full width, and half the height of the superview. Pin the corner buttons to their respective corners, and give them all spacing and equal size constrains like you are now. Don't set any explicit sizes, or an aspect ratio.

Comment: Ok, I can do that.  I added a view with a height of 300 and a Y 300.  this isn't set by constraints, it's just the height.  I set leading to superview, trailing to superview, bottom to bottom layout, and top to top layout, to pin it at the halfway point.  I ran it in the various device simulators.  It seemed to take up half of the space on the phone 5 and 5s.  On the 6 and 6+, it was too tall.  On the 4, it was too short.  I'm missing some fundamental here.

Comment: @Scott You need to set the height with constraints. Select the view, then the superview, then choose `equal heights` from the pin menu. Double click on that constraint, and edit it to make the multiplier 2 or 0.5 (depending on which view is first).